# Referência de objeto não definida para uma instancia de um objeto. C# (na instalação)

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, aplicação-desktop

Pela mensagem do erro, entendi-se que há um objeto não instanciado, no qual eu estaria fazendo referencia.

Erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem, essa mesma aplicação funciona perfeitamente no computador de desenvolvimento, quando eu gero o instalador e instalo em outra maquina esse erro ocorre.

------------------Especificações:

> Aplicação: Desktop.
>
> Visual Studio:2013.
>
> Métodos utilizados para gerar o instador:
>
> 1º Publish(com os aquivos de requisito).
>
> 2º Criação de um projeto Setup-Wizard (estilo Visual Studio 2010).

---

Nas minhas pesquisas no próprio fórum e em outros, esse erro ocorre durante o desenvolvimento, não na instalação. 
Alguém sabe o método realmente correto de  de gerar o instalador no Visual 2013

CarregarPDV():

```
private void CarregarPDV()
    {
        PDV = Model_PDV.Buscar(Ctrl_Configuracao.PDV.Id);
        txtPDV.Text = PDV.Descritivo;
        if (PDV.Status.Equals("False"))
        {
            txtSituacao.Text = "FECHADO";
            btnFechar.Enabled = false;
            btAbrir.Enabled = true;
            Ctrl_Configuracao.CaixaStatus = false;
            txtSituacao.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
        else
        {
            txtSituacao.Text = "ABERTO";
            btnFechar.Enabled = true;
            btAbrir.Enabled = false;
            Ctrl_Configuracao.CaixaStatus = true;
            txtSituacao.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        Model_LogPDV LogCaixa = new Model_LogPDV();
        LogCaixa = Model_LogPDV.BuscaLog(Ctrl_Configuracao.PDV.Id);
        if (LogCaixa.ID_VENDA_START.Equals(""))
        {
            Ctrl_Configuracao.JaVendeu = false;
        }
    }
```

Classe do banco:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Gaivota.Controller;
using Gaivota.View;
using Gaivota.Model;

namespace Gaivota.Model
{

    class Banco
    {
       public static SqlConnection Conexao = new SqlConnection("Data Source=" + Ctrl_Configuracao.Config.DataLink
             + "; Initial Catalog=Gaivota; User Id=sa; Password=123456; Integrated Security=false");

        public static void Abrir()
        {             
            try
            {
                Conexao.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                Ctrl_Msg.MensagemInforma(Ctrl_Msg.ErroAbrirBanco);
            }

        }
        public static void Fechar()
        {
            try
            {
                Conexao.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }

        }
        public static string BuscarCodigoNext(string Tabela)
        {
            string CodigoNovo = "0";
            string sqlstring = "";
            try
            {

                sqlstring = "select ID from " + Tabela + " order by ID desc";
                SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, Banco.Conexao);
                SqlDataReader Ler = Comando.ExecuteReader();

                if (Ler.Read())
                {
                    CodigoNovo = Ler["ID"].ToString();
                    Ler.Close();
                }
                CodigoNovo = (Convert.ToInt32(CodigoNovo) + 1).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            return (CodigoNovo);

        }
        public static string BuscarCodigoAtual(string Tabela)
        {
            string CodigoAtual = "0";
            string sqlstring = "";
            try
            {

                sqlstring = "select ID from " + Tabela + " order by ID desc";
                SqlCommand Comando = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, Banco.Conexao);
                SqlDataReader Ler = Comando.ExecuteReader();

                if (Ler.Read())
                {
                    CodigoAtual = Ler["ID"].ToString();
                    Ler.Close();
                }
                CodigoAtual = (Convert.ToInt32(CodigoAtual)).ToString();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
            return (CodigoAtual);

        }


    }


}
```

classe de configurações:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Gaivota.Model;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;

namespace Gaivota.Controller
{
    class Ctrl_Configuracao
    {
        public static bool RespostaBanco;

        public static bool EstaBuscando;

        public static bool CaixaStatus;

        public static bool JaVendeu = true;

        public static Model_Produto Produto = new Model_Produto();

        public static Model_PDV PDV = new Model_PDV();

        public static Model_Usuario Usuario = new Model_Usuario();

        public static Model_Configuracao Config = new Model_Configuracao();

        public static Model_RelPDV RelPDV = new Model_RelPDV();

        public static string XML_Link = @"C:\Gaivota\config.xml";

        public static  Model_Configuracao LerXML()
        {
            Model_Configuracao Configuracao = new Model_Configuracao();
            Configuracao.PortaCOM = null;
            try
            {
                //Cria uma instância de um documento XML
                XmlDocument oXML = new XmlDocument();

                //carrega o arquivo XML
                oXML.Load(XML_Link);

                //Lê o filho de um Nó Pai específico 
                Configuracao.ModeloPrint = oXML.SelectSingleNode("config").ChildNodes[0].InnerText;
                Configuracao.PortaCOM = oXML.SelectSingleNode("config").ChildNodes[1].InnerText;
                Configuracao.Velocidade = oXML.SelectSingleNode("config").ChildNodes[2].InnerText;
                Configuracao.DataLink = oXML.SelectSingleNode("config").ChildNodes[3].InnerText;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Ctrl_Msg.MensagemInforma(Ctrl_Msg.ErroLerXML);
            }

            return Configuracao;
        }

        public static void SetConfig()
        {       

         Ctrl_Configuracao.Config  = Ctrl_Configuracao.LerXML();  


        }
        public static bool SomenteNumeros(int key)
        {
            bool x = true;

            if (key < 48 || key > 57)
            {
                if (key == 8)
                {
                    x = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    x = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                x = false;
            }

            return (x);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o seu método frmMenu_load(..) e carregarPDV(...)

Comment: Talvez precise de outras partes da classe usada em `frmMenu`. O problema talvez nem seja o local onde está e sim a situação em que é usado. Não adianta testar pra ver se funciona, tem que testar pra ver se não funciona.

Comment: Amigo, eu postei, mas  é como se  a aplicação mate-se minha classe de configuração.

Comment: @JonathanHenrique Isto certamente é erro de programação. Já posso adiantar que tem várias coisas esquisitas e problemáticas neste código. Qual é a linha onde ocorre o erro. Mostre ela, o número não tem como sabermos qual é.

Comment: O que retorna em `Model_PDV.Buscar()`? Melhor ainda seria colocá-lo. O mesmo vale `Model_LogPDV.BuscaLog()`.

Comment: Olha, agradeço a atenção. Mas acho que eu não me expressei direito. 
O sistema FUNCIONA na maquina que estou desenvolvendo, quando gera o instalador que esse erro ocorre.

Comment: @JonathanHenrique vou ser bem sincero com você, você pode não gostar, mas no momento é o que posso fazer de melhor pra você. Seu código é bastante confuso e é muito fácil ele estar se perdendo em determinada situação. Testar em uma situação e funcionar não quer dizer nada além de que naquela situação funciona. Estar certo é uma coisa bem diferente. Se estivesse certo funcionaria em todas situações. Se você postar o que eu pedi (e provavelmente teria que pedir outras coisas, porque é assim que acha erro) eu poderia ajudar mais e dizer o que tem que mudar no código.

Answer (score -1):

O problema pode estar no método `Equals(...)`, é necessário mais detalhes do seu problema para sabermos ao certo o que ocorre

O problema pode estar aqui:

```
PDV.Status.Equals("False");
```

Ou aqui:

```
LogCaixa.ID_VENDA_START.Equals("");
```

Se o `PDV.Status` ou `LogCaixa.ID_VENDA_START` for nulo o erro mencionado irá ocorrer, pois o objeto não está instanciado.

Recomendo que você substitua o `.Equals(...)` por `==`

Então no seu método ficaria assim:

```
if (PDV.Status=="False")
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Ou pode estar em várias outras linhas.

Comment: Provavelmente, é necessário mais detalhes. Esse foi um detalhe que eu vi que pode ser o causador do erro.

Comment: Então espera ele colocar, ainda não dá para responder.

Comment: Caros, se o erro fosse no if (PDV.Status=="False"). Não era para não funcionar nas duas maquinas ? E não somente na de teste ?